# View not being added to top view controller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add a activity indicator (which is an activity indicator view) to the view after a particular button is pressed. The button's code is not in that viewcontroller's swift file, though, and is in instead in a customclass swift file, which 'interacts' (not sure if that terminology is correct?) with the viewcontroller swift file. My code prompts no errors, but it just doesn't work correctly. No activityindicator is show on the view, and the screen should stop accepting user inputs but it does not. I have posted the relevant bits of code below:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
            var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
            while (topController?.presentedViewController != nil) {
                topController = topController?.presentedViewController
            }
            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
            activityIndicator.center = topController!.view.center //centers the indicator
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
            topController!.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            return topController!
        }
    }
}
```

If the amount of closure's are incorrect, that's not the issue... that is just me screwing up the copying and pasting of relevant code bits. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Hmm...you want to show the indicator in the cell's viewController? Am i right? Why are you putting the function inside the action function? If you put in there, shouldnt you call it?

Comment: @TJ3n You are correct that that is what I want to do. I have the function in there because I am not sure how to 'get' (terminology?) the top viewcontroller to add the activity indicator to it

Comment: Why dont you use delegate and tell the parentVC to show the indicator instead?

Comment: @Tj3n, that sounds significantly more simple... what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: create a protocol for the cell, let the cell take it property, and let the parentVC implement that protocol and delegate, then whenever the user touch the button, the cell will tell your parent VC to execute some code, try google on how to implement delegate

Comment: @Tj3n the cell actually already has a protocol set up, and the parentVC uses it. I just don't know how to get it to tell the parentVC to run the code... since I don't really know how to refer to it correctly from this custom class (hence this question)

Comment: In the `cellForRow` set your `cell.delegate = self`, then in the action function u call `delegate?.yourFunction()`, so you tell the delegate here which is your parentVC, to execute code in `yourFunction()`, there are many tutorial on setting up this, is not very hard also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121027/discussion-between-alek-piasecki-and-tj3n).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `bringSubviewToFront` to bring the indicator on front.

```
topController!.view.bringSubviewToFront(activityIndicator)
```

Comment: Should this be before or after the "start animating" bit of code? And does there need to be an opposite type of call when I want to turn the activity indicator off?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you start animation before or after. You set `hidesWhenStopped` to `true` so the indicator will automatically be hidden when you stop it with `stopAnimation()`.

Comment: As @grimfrog said, it will not matter. If you set hidesWhenStopped to true. ActivityIndicator will do it for you automatically. But you need to bring it to front view so that it will be the topmost view or window.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {\
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
       let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Some Message
       ", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    alert.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()  
    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    alertVc = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.rootViewController = alertVc
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    alertWindow.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: handler)

    }
}
```

Comment: How would you later call to close the alert?

Comment: you can add a function for dismissing

              alertVc?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:      handler)
             alertVc = nil





or add action for dismissing alert